# pass extension name while building vscode extension (vsix)

Tags: gradle, vscode-extensions

I am currently building vscode extension for multiple platform (extension include jre) who do I pass extension name while building vscode extension.

I found this [article](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension)  but in gradle who do I set extension name?

Package.json
[image]

extension name got overridden with package.json name.

**build.gradle**

```
task buildLinuxExtension(type: NpxTask) {
    description "Build the vsix extension package"
    dependsOn compileLinuxExtension
    command = 'cd'
    args = ['LinuxExtension']
    command = 'vsce'
    args = ['package']
}
``
```

Comment: can you show us your package.json file?

Comment: @Delanovanlonden Added package.json snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can parse package.json in build.gradle and set name.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def void setExtensionName(String extensionName){
 def packageSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
 def packageJson = packageSlurper.parse file('package.json')
 packageJson.name = extensionName
 def json_str = JsonOutput.toJson(packageJson)
 def json_beauty = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json_str)
 File file = new File("package.json")
 file.write(json_beauty)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `vsce` to generate the extension package, you can call a command like `sed` to replace `"name": "test",` with `"name": "LinuxExtension",` in `package.json`, if that's what you wanted.

With search engines you can find decades of knowledge around `sed` or similar command line tools.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this workaround. In gradle i am able to parse package.json and modified name.

Comment: @NagarajKandoor then I suggest you accept your own answer, which actually is better with cross platform support.